# Can Azure compile TypeScript and execute Gulp tasks?

Tags: azure, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core

I'm developing .NET Core app with TypeScript + Angular 2. And I want to deploy that on Azure. When I do this, I see the following build error after Azure get code from my repository:

**"VSTSC : error TS5023: Build: Unknown compiler option 'lib'. [D:\home\site\repository\AC.API\AC.API.xproj]"**

My `tsconfig.json` is following:

```
  {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Locally everything works fine. If I remove "**lib**" section in `tsconfig.json` I can't compile solution locally.

So, I have some questions. Can Azure compile TypeScript and execute Gulp tasks? How can I change version of TypeScript on Azure? Or how can I resolve my issue?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do it within Continuous Integration and Deployment. You definitely  can do it in Visual Studio Team Service.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because Azure just a cloud service to host your web application so you have to manage compile process in your build like Continus Integration in Azure Devops and deploy the code to Azure using their release pipeline.

You can found out the detail in [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/pipelines/)

Hope it help.